# Count specific XML Nodes within XML

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

See this XML:

---

```
<CMP>
    <OMP3>
        <personmenu>
            <submenuid>502</submenuid>
            <submenuid>503</submenuid>
        </personmenu>
        <accountsmenu>
            <submenuid>517</submenuid>
            <submenuid>518</submenuid>
            <submenuid>519</submenuid>
        </accountsmenu>

        <reportsmenu>
            <submenuid>522</submenuid>
            <submenuid>528</submenuid>
            <submenuid>536</submenuid>
        </reportsmenu>
    </OMP3>

    <AMP3>
        <admissionmenu>
            <submenuid>702</submenuid>
            <submenuid>703</submenuid>
        </admissionmenu>
    </AMP3>
</CMP>
```

---

I want to get the total count of  nodes from this xml dynamically (C#).
How can I do it? Any sample code?

Comment: Which nodes do you wish to count?

Comment: what do mean by count all. you want to count e.g submenuid elements or all elements in xml document?

Answer (score 13):

Here's an example of counting all `submenuid` nodes in your xml document without loading it into memory:

```
var nodeCount = 0;
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create("test.xml"))
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && 
            reader.Name == "submenuid")
        {
            nodeCount++;
        }
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(nodeCount);
```

Or if you prefer LINQ to XML:

```
var count = XDocument
    .Load("test.xml")
    .XPathSelectElements("//submenuid")
    .Count();
```

Answer (score 6):

Use XmlDocument like this:

```
XmlDocument xmlD = new XmlDocument();
xmlD.Load(Server.MapPath("sample.xml"));
XmlNodeList xmlNL = xmlD.GetElementsByTagName("tagName");
xmlNL.Count;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use XPath function "count" as well. here is a example.

```
XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument("c:\\test.xml");
int count = (int)doc.CreateNavigator().Evaluate("count(//submenuid)");
```

Comment: This worked for me but I had to cast to double.  It's been ten years since this post so this is most likely a change in the XML library functions since 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Below code is to find the count of a specific node in the `XML Document`

```
 private void browse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//file browse button
    {
        DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            String file = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            if (Path.GetExtension(file) != ".xml")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please upload an vaild xml file");
                textBox1.Clear();
            }
            else
            {
                textBox1.Text = file;
            }
        }
    }  
 private void CountButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//count button
    {
        int count = 0;
        string element = textBox2.Text;//Enter the node in the textbox
        XmlDocument readdoc = new XmlDocument();
            readdoc.Load(textBox1.Text);
            XmlElement root = readdoc.DocumentElement;
            XmlNodeList node = root.GetElementsByTagName(element);
            count = node.Count;
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Count of {0} node in the uploaded xml file is {1}", element, count.ToString()));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you have control of your xml**

```
string xmlReturn="
<CMP>
<OMP3>
    <personmenu>
        <submenuid>502</submenuid>
        <submenuid>503</submenuid>
    </personmenu>
    <accountsmenu>
        <submenuid>517</submenuid>
        <submenuid>518</submenuid>
        <submenuid>519</submenuid>
    </accountsmenu>

    <reportsmenu>
        <submenuid>522</submenuid>
        <submenuid>528</submenuid>
        <submenuid>536</submenuid>
    </reportsmenu>
</OMP3>

<AMP3>
    <admissionmenu>
        <submenuid>702</submenuid>
        <submenuid>703</submenuid>
    </admissionmenu>
</AMP3>
</CMP>"
XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
xmldoc.LoadXml(xmlReturn);
XmlNodeList nodeListCount=xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("submenuid");
int nodeCount = nodeListCount.Count;
Console.WriteLine(nodeCount);
```